# Find all nodes that contain punctuation marks

Tags: vb.net

I have an extremely large XML file and within each main node there is a child node

```
<term>text, text</term>
```

Some of these child nodes have punctuation marks as shown above, but which punctuation mark is not known. I need to get a list of all of the punctuation marks used in these child nodes so that I can visually inspect them and later replace them all with just one punctuation mark.

I've tried using the regex `/<term>[[:punct:]]<\/term>` but it finds no matches in the regex tester.

How can I copy all of the punctuation marks used in the child node into a text file?

How can I replace all punctuation marks in the child node by a semi-colon?

Here is a sample node, there are two occurrences of  in each node.

```
<conceptGrp><descripGrp><descrip type="subjectField">6821</descrip></descripGrp><languageGrp><language lang="DE" type="German" /><termGrp><term>Betonkanal BE;Betonkanal breites Ei</term><descripGrp><descrip type="termType">phraseologicalUnit</descrip></descripGrp><descripGrp><descrip type="reliabilityCode">2</descrip></descripGrp></termGrp></languageGrp><languageGrp><language lang="EN" type="English" /><termGrp><term>flattened egg-shaped concrete sewer</term><descripGrp><descrip type="termType">phraseologicalUnit</descrip></descripGrp><descripGrp><descrip type="reliabilityCode">2</descrip></descripGrp></termGrp></languageGrp></conceptGrp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can use [\p{P}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#CategoryOrBlock) to match punctuation characters. So, assuming you have some way of iterating over the XML nodes you need to examine...

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim x = <root>
                    <term>No punctuation</term>
                    <term>Here be... dots</term>
                    <term>No, there isn't a semi-colon here.</term>
                </root>

        Dim re As New Regex("\p{P}")

        For Each a In x.Descendants
            Dim puncs = re.Matches(a.Value)
            If puncs.Count > 0 Then
                For Each m As Match In puncs
                    'TODO: Write to a file instead of the Console.
                    Console.Write(m.Groups(0).Value)
                Next

                Console.WriteLine()

            End If
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

outputs

> ...
>   ,'-.

For the second part of the question, you can use

```
For Each a In x.Descendants
    Dim newValue = re.Replace(a.Value, ";")
    'TODO: update the value of the node
    Console.WriteLine(newValue)
Next
```

which outputs

> No punctuation
>   Here be;;; dots
>   No; there isn;t a semi;colon here;

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Your regex picks all the punctuation marks if they are followed by a space otherwise it skips them. I am am expecting pipe symbols with no spaces either side and these are also not picked up. I suppose a better description might be characters that are not whitespace, letters or numbers. I played around with [[:punct:]] but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @BenS If you look at the last character of the last <term> element you will see it is a full stop which is *not* followed by a space (or any other character) and it was picked up by the regex. You could use `[\p{P}|]` to include pipe characters. Please edit your question to include everything we need to know so it is easier for us to help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering but I was on the road. I have a large xml file which represents a bilingual glossary and is the conglomeration of many other glossaries from various sources. In the term node there can be synonyms separated by a "special" character. All of these separators are unknown but could be commas, semicolons, colons, pipes or some other character. I first need to find out what separators have been used and then replace with a semicolon. Your regex did work exactly as you said, I had just tried it in a Tester and it didn't.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I implemented this regex on a twenty line sample file: 'Dim re As New Regex("<term>[a-zA-Z\d\s]*([^a-zA-Z\d\s^äöüßÄÖÜ])[a-zA-Z\d\s]*<\/term>")'. I need to exclude the German special charactere amd umlauts. In the Expresso regex Tester it works fine, but I can't get my code in VS to compile because when it reaches an ampersand (&) in the file text I get the error message "XML entity references are not supported." There are  literally 2897 ampersands in the file, too many to manually edit, so how can I get VS to ignore them in the file text?

Comment: @BenS It is not the ampersand which is the problem, it is that a character entity not specified for XML 1.0 is present: [XML entity references are not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/bb531286(v=vs.110).aspx). It could be that there are few enough of the unsupported character entities are in the file to search-and-replace them to get an XML 1.0-compliant file which will work with your program.

Comment: Thanks for that Andrew. I have changed the ampersands to '&amp;' and now my test data and the full file can be processed without any errors. Thanks for your help, you have answered my question.